# WP Title - Static Homepage Title Missing Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

The home static page will only display the name of the site and not the page title in wordpress

was functionality for this deprecated?

Comment: have you tried installing the `All in one SEO plugin`

Comment: I can't because the site is maxed out on plugins. In addition, someone hotrodded the theme.

Comment: It could be something to do with the theme itself. Maybe it doesn't show it? Or maybe there is just a css style hiding the title?

Comment: Could be down to lots of things. Maybe you can provide more info about your set-up?

Comment: !-- website title -->
<title>name</title>
<title>name, name®</title> This is what the source code looks like. Nopage title just the domain name.

Comment: <!-- website title -->
<title><?php wp_title( '', true ); ?></title> - this is the header code...

Comment: <!-- website title -->
<title><?php the_title( '', true ); ?></title>  I changed it to this BUT it writes like this  keywords1 - domain name is blank